# opendkim requires libcrypto

Tags: ssl, dkim, epel

I am trying to install opendkim. For that, I used rpm to install epel, then did yum install opendkim. However, I get the following dependency errors:

Error: Package: opendkim-2.9.0-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1)(64bit)

Error: Package: libopendkim-2.9.0-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit)

Error: Package: opendkim-2.9.0-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit)

Error: Package: opendkim-2.9.0-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit)

As far as I can tell, this is because I'm running openssl 1.0.0, and it's looking for 1.0.1. I feel like I should update openssl, but I'm not sure how, and I'm a little nervous to do that. Can anyone tell me if this is in fact what I need to do? This may be a duplicate question but I don't understand the answer: https://serverfault.com/questions/571093/why-yum-update-php-doesnt-have-required-dependencies-centos-6-missing-libcrypt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your system.

RHEL (and CentOS) switched from OpenSSL 1.0.0 to 1.0.1 during the 6.4-6.5 cycle in order to [resolve a years-long issue](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=319901). As a result any programs which use OpenSSL had to be rebuilt for 6.5.

Since EPEL only tracks the latest point release, and its software is only guaranteed to run on the latest point release, you need to update to 6.5.

A simple `yum --disableexcludes=all upgrade` should take care of it.

Comment: Thanks Michael! Before I try this -- will it work even though I'm currently running CentOS 6.4?

Comment: That's the whole point!

Comment: OK, sorry, misunderstood and wanted to be on the safe side. I just ran yum --disableexcludes=all upgrade and tried again, but I get the same list of dependency errors. Also when I check, I notice that I still have CentOS 6.4.

Comment: Something is terribly wrong with your system. Are you sure you are actually using CentOS and that it hasn't been tampered with or reconfigured? In particular check the `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` file and make sure it hasn't been redirected to something other than official CentOS repositories.

Comment: Ugh. That sounds bad. I'm sure I'm running CentOs, yes. I'm the only one with access, unless I've been hacked, and I've never reconfigured it. When I ran your command above, then checked to see what version of CentOs I had, it still said "CentOS release 6.4 (Final)"

Comment: Actually, when I ran your command, it says, "No Packages marked for Update"

Comment: Did you check the file I asked you to check?

Comment: Sorry, yes, didn't see that part until after I posted. I have it open now. How do I know if it's been redirected?

Comment: It should be blatantly obvious if something is wrong with it. Do the repos point to `mirrorlist.centos.org` and `mirror.centos.org` or not?

Comment: All the centos.org mirrors have been commented out with # and replaced with http://p3plmirror01.prod.phx3.secureserver.net/vph/2/download/mirrors/cos-$releasever-centosplus.$basearch, which I think is GoDaddy's mirror? (This is a GoDaddy VPS.)

Comment: That explains the problem. GoDaddy tampered with it. Go download [a copy of the `centos-release` RPM from an official mirror](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/centos-release-6-5.el6.centos.11.1.x86_64.rpm) to your VPS and run `yum reinstall` with it. That should clean things up. Actually I think you can just pass the URL directly to yum... Then go back to my original answer at the top...

Comment: OK that was it! I did a variation on what you said -- I went into /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo and commented out all of godaddy's mirrors and uncommented all of centos.org's mirrors and restarted. Then I did your answer above. Worked like a charm! The system updated. I was able to install opendkim without a hitch. After restarting apache and postfix, my mails are now working. Thank you Michael!!! (PS -- will the changes I made to Base.repo cause any problems down the road? Restoring centos.org's mirrors?)

Comment: No. If you updated, you would have picked up the new `centos-release` RPM anyway. Take a look, and you will probably see that all of GoDaddy's changes are gone entirely.